# Is it possible to combine gulp watch with jasmine-spec-reporter

Tags: javascript, gulp, jasmine

I'm trying to combine watch with the [jasmine-spec-reporter](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter), this is my gulpfile:

```
import Jasmine from 'jasmine';
import SpecReporter from 'jasmine-spec-reporter';

gulp.task('watch', () => {
  gulp.watch('./spec/**/*[sS]pec.js', ['jasmine']);
});

gulp.task('jasmine', () => {
  let jasmine = new Jasmine();
  jasmine.env.clearReporters();
  jasmine.addReporter(new SpecReporter());
  jasmine.loadConfigFile();
  jasmine.execute();
});
```

#### Problem

If I run `gulp jasmine` it works fine, but if I run the watch task it executes just once:

```
$ gulp watch
> Starting 'watch'...
> Finished 'watch' after 8.82 ms
> Starting 'jasmine'...
> Spec started
> 
>   MyClass
>   ✓ exists
>   ✓ has a size
> 
>   add()
>     ✓ is a function
>     ✓ increases the size
> 
>   myFunction()
>     ✓ is a function
> 
> Executed 5 of 5 specs SUCCESS in 0.007 sec.
$
```

#### Question

Is it possible to run the jasmine-spec-runner with gulp so it executes continuously if the watch task triggers?

Comment: My current quickfix is that I spawn a script that calls itself, after the gulp watch task finished

`#!/bin/bash
gulp watch && ./$0`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the singleRun switch in your `Karma.conf.js` config file?

```
singleRun: false
```

I'm assuming you're using Karma

Comment: I'm not using Karma, only Jasmine - is there a difference in how the tests are executed with Jasmine in my node environment and Karma with a headless browser like PhantomJS? Are there any disadvantages if I switch to Karma and use PhantomJS?